# Communicate Android with WebApp - Receive orders by php

Tags: php, android, web-services, synchronization

I have to make an application that receives commands from a website and therefore perform an action.

I thought about creating a login in android to send the username and password for POST and if this is correct, the web server will return a unique token. That would serve me later to send information to the server and ensure authentication...

But ... how can my android application know when the website has a warrant for?

I've thought about that all the time is pending a URL "checkOrders" and if it finds your token, request orders to another URL

Anybody know other method to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the only (battery and otherwise) efficient way is using push notifications. Unfortunately, this approach is not even close to being simple.

Since you're developing an Android application, you may want to consider [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and [Parse Push](https://parse.com/products/push). If you're planing on developing apps for iOS and Windows phones in the future, I'd strongly recommend Parse Push. At the moment, it's free for up to one million users.

Hyperlink for GCM will lead you to generally useful reading on this topic. That's why I am not elaborating here.

Comment: You think that would consume much battery check every 5 seconds if a URL is written your token (if contain a text with a hash SHA1, per example)? As I explained earlier, if the app is the token passes to check the work (which could be many) and send data to the Web application. GCM seems too complicated...

Comment: @MartaGom: Even push is not that gentle. If you look at different services on the web (hard enough), you'll find battery consumption estimates. To make this short, checking every 5 seconds is going to drain device's battery really, really fast. It's unacceptable for a commercial application and will be easily noted. Of course, I assume these check would be frequent and entire process durable. If not, you may try checking every 5 seconds.

Comment: I understand... And the "Parse Push" system... Is easy to use? Or  is complicated like GCM? Thank for your help.

Comment: @MartaGom: Parse will be easier, yes. I decided to use it for my instant messaging app.
If you find this answer helpful, please check it as accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, I forgot check your answer. Thanks for your advices.